# Endpoint Deactivation MQ Adapter BPEL

Tags: adapter, bpel, mq

I am using BPEL process (AIA) to pick message from MQ (Message Queue). MQ Adapter picks message from the queue against a defined schema(nxsd). The nxsd schema has style as terminated. The issue is when an incorrect message is placed onto the queue the process continuously picks message from the queue rejects it and places it back onto the queue. This happens continuously.

Please help as this has caused a lot of server issues

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MQ BPEL adapter guy. I come from MQ background.

MQ Adapter may have ability to route messages that are not understood by it to another queue known as a BACKOUT QUEUE (or BOQNAME in WebSphere MQ). Messages that are not understood by adapter (or for that matter JMS layer) are called `poison messages`.

There will also be another parameter typically called as a 'Threshold' (`BOTHRESH` in WebSphere MQ). This attribute tells the adapter when to route the message to a backout queue. For example if the attribute is set to 3, then if the same message is received 3 times (and is sent back to the same queue because the adapter does not understands this message), then when the message arrives for the fourth time, the message is automatically moved to backout queue.

My suggestion would be to look into MQ BPEL adapter documentation to see if it supports Backout queue and threshold attributes. If yes, set these attributes appropriately and try.